# C: Raycaster not working

Tags: c, 3d, terminal, ascii, raycasting

I tried to make an ascii raycaster in C that runs in the terminal. I don't think anything like that has been done before. It doesn't seem to print the frames correctly. Hopefully someone can tell me what the problem is. Here is my code: https://ghostbin.com/paste/9vxmz
I was expecting the program to display a maze (stored in the map array) in first person. I didn't implement controls yet. Basically, there is a two dimensional char array that is the size of the terminal screen. This array is supposed to print every second. The screen array gets its values from a raycaster. I don't know exactly where the problem is, but it isn't that big of a program. Plz help I'm totally new to C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int getrows();
int getcols();
double diagnalMovementX(double x, double angle);
double diagnalMovementY(double y, double angle);
#define ROWS getrows()              // the amount of horisontal rows in the terminal
#define COLS getcols()              // the amount of verticle columns in the terminal
#define PI 3.14159265358979         // defines pi
#define TAU 2*PI                // makes things easier because TAU is 360 degrees in radians
#define DTOR PI/180             // multiply by this to convert degrees to radians
#define RTOD 180/PI             // multiply by this to convert radians to degrees
int currentframe=0;             // the current frame
const int map[13][12]={             // the actual map
    {1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
    {1,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1},
    {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1},
    {1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1},
    {1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1}
};
int main() {
    char screen[COLS][ROWS];        // this array is modified and printed every frame
    double posX=2, posY=0;          // position for the player
    double direction=0*DTOR;        // direction of the player
    double fov=0*DTOR;          // the feild of vision
    double angleBetweenEachRay=fov/COLS;    // the angle between each ray
    double rayX, rayY;          // the position of the end of the ray
    double rayAngle;            // the angle that the ray travels
    double distanceToWall;          // the distance the player is away from a wall
    int lineHeight;             // how many columns the wall should use on the screen
    int sizeOfBlankSpaces;          // the size that the ceiling and floor should appear on the screen
    int thisIntPreventsCrashes=0;       // prevents a ray from traveling endlessly

    // gameloop starts here
    while (1) {
        // this allows movement
        /* NOT IMPLEMENTED YET */
        // this loop generates the columns of the frame
        for (int i=0; i<COLS; i++) {
            // calculate the ray angle
            rayAngle=direction-fov/2-angleBetweenEachRay+angleBetweenEachRay*(i+1);
            // fix the ray angle if it is not a proper value
            if (rayAngle>TAU) {
                rayAngle-=TAU;
            }
            else if (rayAngle<0) {
                rayAngle+=TAU;
            }
            // makes the ray start from the player
            rayX=posX;
            rayY=posY;
            // increases the ray size
            rayX=diagnalMovementX(rayX, rayAngle);
            rayY=diagnalMovementY(rayY, rayAngle);
            // this code prevents the ray from traveling endlessly and the game from freezing if there is no wall for the ray to hit
            thisIntPreventsCrashes++;
            if (thisIntPreventsCrashes>10) {
                lineHeight=0;
            }
            // checks if the ray hit a wall
            if (map[(int) rayY][(int) rayX]==1) {
                // calculates the distance to the wall using the distance formula
                distanceToWall=sqrt(pow((rayX-posX), 2)+pow((rayY-posY), 2));
                // calculates the size the wall should appear onscreen
                lineHeight=ROWS/(10*distanceToWall);
            }
            // shows X when there is no wall
            if (lineHeight==0) {
                for (int ii=0; ii<ROWS; ii++) {
                    screen[i][ii]='X';
                }
            }
            else {
                // calculates the ceiling and floor size
                sizeOfBlankSpaces=(ROWS-lineHeight)/2;
                // ceiling
                for(int ii=0; ii<sizeOfBlankSpaces; ii++) {
                    screen[i][ii]=' ';
                }
                // walls
                for(int ii=sizeOfBlankSpaces; ii<sizeOfBlankSpaces+lineHeight; ii++) {
                    screen[i][ii]='';
                }
                // floor
                for(int ii=sizeOfBlankSpaces+lineHeight; ii<ROWS; ii++) {
                    screen[i][ii]=' ';
                }
            }
        }
        // this sets the framerate
        sleep(1);
        // this clears the current frame
        fflush(stdout);
        //this code prints a new frame
        for (int iy=0; iy<ROWS; iy++) {
            for (int ix=0; ix<COLS; ix++) {
                printf("%c", screen[iy][ix]);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
        currentframe++;
    }
    return 0;
}
int getrows() {
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
    return w.ws_row;
}
int getcols() {
    struct winsize w;
    ioctl(0, TIOCGWINSZ, &w);
    return w.ws_col;
}
double diagnalMovementX(double x, double angle) {
    if (angle<TAU && angle>0.5*TAU) {
        x-=0.5*cos(angle);
    }
    else if (angle>0 && angle<0.5*TAU) {
        x+=0.5*cos(angle);
    }
    return x;
}
double diagnalMovementY(double y, double angle) {
    if (angle<TAU && angle>0.5*TAU) {
        if (angle<0.75*TAU) {
            y-=0.5*sin(angle);
        }
        else if (angle>0.75*TAU) {
            y+=0.5*sin(angle);
        }
    }
    else if (angle>0 && angle<0.5*TAU) {
        if (angle<0.25*TAU) {
            y+=0.5*sin(angle);
        }
        else if (angle>0.25*TAU) {
            y-=0.5*sin(angle);
        }
    }
    else if (angle==0 || angle==TAU) {
        y+=0.5;
    }
    else if (angle==0.5*TAU) {
        y-=0.5;
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code to the question? I can't even view the link.

Comment: I added the code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

`fflush(stdout);` after your frame printing nested `for`s

Comment: Try a single frame. Can you get that to render properly?

Comment: I can't. It just shows random characters, but the same characters every frame. The frame isn't even the full size of the terminal.

Comment: There's an error in your output  `for (iy=0; iy<ROWS; iy++)
   for (ix=0; ix<COLS; ix++)
    printf("%c", screen[ix][iy]);` You should be using `screen[iy][ix]`

Comment: That definately helps, but I still don't see anything in the maze. The top half of the screen is filled with the character that is supposed to be the walls, and the bottom half doesn't have anything.

Comment: What about if you set this to only do one frame, but redirect the program's output to a text file, e.g. `myProg > testout.txt`

Comment: When I run "cat testout.txt", the frame displays the same as before, but when I open it in gedit, it says "There was a problem opening the file" and shows the same character for the top half, but a lot of red backslashes followed by zeros for the bottom half.

Comment: I tried moving posX and posY to a different location. Now there are diagonal stripes in each frame.

Comment: I see a line `screen[i][ii]='';`. This probably isn't what you want. Try ' ' instead.

Comment: That line is supposed to add the walls to the screen array. I do have a character there, but it doesn't show in the paste.